# angular 6 element boolean input parameter

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-elements

I'm building out an **angular element** and passing some input params to it.  I can pass some string input params just fine (ikrId and environment work perfectly) but struggling to pass a boolean value to the showTitle input property through an **angular element** (passing the showTitle property to the component from a parent angular component works just fine).

Here's component snippet:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @Input() ikrId: string;
  @Input('environment') environment: IkrEnvironment = 'PROD';
  @Input('showTitle') showTitle = true;
```

Here is how I'm using it in **plain old html**:

```
<my-element environment="DEV" ikr-id="889fb69f-71a5-4881-8528-0b43a07599f0" show-title="false"></my-element>
```

But show title is not getting passed into my component, it's always true.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could define the `showTitle` property as a getter/setter, and convert the string value to a boolean in the setter:

```
private _showTitle = true;

@Input('showTitle') 
get showTitle(): boolean {
  return this._showTitle;
}
set showTitle(value: boolean) {
  this._showTitle = "" + value !== "false";
}
```

Comment: That is true for using this component from a parent angular component, but I'm specfically having in issue using this as an angular element.  https://angular.io/guide/elements

Comment: How are you passing your input elements? If you pre-load your input items, you should not have any issues using resolvers in your route. Then use activated route to pass your items to <my-element.. Just trying to help. I had a questionhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/47874927/why-images-blink-on-safari-but-does-not-in-chrome-when-the-app-resizes. I had to preload the data to solve my issues.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I guess the only things I can send as Input params to the angular element are string variables, which makes sense because I need to provide them from html element attributes.

Answer (score 1):

the syntax to pass Input in the template is `[<input_name>]="<value>"`; you should use

```
<my-element [environment]="DEV" [ikrId]="889fb69f-71a5-4881-8528-0b43a07599f0" [showTitle]="false"></my-element>
```

Comment: When you add the `[]` around the attribute names, the values will be evaluated as expressions.  That means that any literal strings must be wrapped in quotes (inside the outer quotes), such as `[environment]="'DEV'"`.

Comment: Your answer applies to an Angular app but most likely the web compomnent will not be used inside another Angular app

Answer (score 0):

Boolean conversion can be done with a getter.

```
@Input('showTitle') showTitleStr: string;
get showTitle() {
    return this.showTitleStr === "true";
}
```