# Angular Boolean Input String

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to create a reusable component. My expectation is that the value of masDisabled when not set to false or true will always be true. I still want the masDisabled construct like that, not [masDisabled]. But I have a problem, all components that do not have the masDisabled property are also disabled. How to solve it?

test.component.html

```
<mas-button masDisabled></mas-button>
```

button.component.html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="disabledMas"></button>
```

button.component.ts

```
disabledMas = true;

@Input('disabledMas')
get masDisabled(): boolean {
    return this.disabledMas;
}
set masDisabled(value: boolean) {
    this.disabledMas = value === false;
}
```

Comment: when i set
disabledMas = false; and also set
this.disabledMas = value === true;

All button components will be active, including those with the masDisabled property

Comment: so where should I set undefined? in get or set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong attribute name. You can see in [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-73724385-original?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmas-button%2Fmas-button.component.ts) that your getter and setter are not even being hit!

In your component, it's called `@Input('disabledMas')`, but in your component template, you use a different name `<mas-button masDisabled></mas-button>`.

Once you correct that, you'll see an error if you don't set a boolean value, so you should do it like this:

```js
<mas-button [disabledMas]="true"></mas-button>
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-73724385?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmas-button%2Fmas-button.component.ts).

---

It doesn't seem like you really need a getter and setter at all, I think something like this would work:

```js
@Input() disabledMas = false;
```

```html
[disabled]="!disabledMas"
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-73724385-solution2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmas-button%2Fmas-button.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmas-button%2Fmas-button.component.html) demo.

---

EDIT:

Since you want your default (attribute not present) to be visible, we will default `disabled` to false.

Since you don't want to pass a value, the passed value will be an empty string.  So, we can use the setter to compare with an empty string to determine if it's `disabled`:

```js
  isDisabled = false;

  @Input() set masDisabled(value: string) {
    this.isDisabled = value === '' || value === 'true';
  }
```

Comment: as I said before, the expectations I hope for do not use brackets, just masDisabled. I have tried the example from the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52526796/angular-6-element-boolean-input-parameter, but still failed

Comment: Okay, I think I get what you're going for, try this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-73724385-solution3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmas-button%2Fmas-button.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmas-button%2Fmas-button.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Wow........ it's going well, thank you